# Representing graph data in a pictorial and statistical way

Tags: graph, pytorch, graph-neural-network

The Data set is a Heterogeneous graph datasets, with multiple types of nodes and edges. DBLP : Citation network dataset

**DBLP Dataset folder link:** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IBWp07mY6Xuzhi7XZU0bRSikEbdPbkar?usp=sharing

**DBLP Data-set features:**

1. Edge (4 type , Paper-Author, Author-Paper, Paper-Conference and Conference-Paper)
2. Node features (3 type of nodes; Papers (P), Authors (A), Conferences(C))
3. Labels (Features, Research areas of each Author)
   [image: A pictorial representation of the dataset and the labels]

**Dataset contains :**
`Nodes = 18405, Edges = 67946, Edge type = 4, Features = 334,  Training = 800, Validation = 400, Test = 2857.`

> Questions:

**Q1)** Can someone please suggest me a good way in which I can present this dataset in a meaningful, what all can I implement?

1. A pictorial graph presentation an
2. In a more statistical way using statistics (plots, histograms etc).

Currently the code uses these lines to implement:

```
$ python main.py --dataset DBLP --num_layers 3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# Some lines of code with a few arguments passed into parser.parse_args()

args = parser.parse_args()

with open('data/'+args.dataset+'/node_features.pkl','rb') as f:
    node_features = pickle.load(f)
with open('data/'+args.dataset+'/edges.pkl','rb') as f:
    edges = pickle.load(f)
with open('data/'+args.dataset+'/labels.pkl','rb') as f:
    labels = pickle.load(f)
```

Full reference of the code: [link](https://github.com/anshumansinha16/GTN-copy/blob/master/main.py)

Comment: This question is too broad and needs some focus.

Comment: @Ivan Shall I edit this question and post 2 different questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python [Multigraphs](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/tutorial.html#multigraphs) from networkx library to represent your graph. It is easy to use.

Here is the example from [1](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/tutorial.html#multigraphs)

```
MG = nx.MultiGraph()
MG.add_weighted_edges_from([(1, 2, 0.5), (1, 2, 0.75), (2, 3, 0.5)])
dict(MG.degree(weight='weight'))
{1: 1.25, 2: 1.75, 3: 0.5}
GG = nx.Graph()
for n, nbrs in MG.adjacency():
   for nbr, edict in nbrs.items():
       minvalue = min([d['weight'] for d in edict.values()])
       GG.add_edge(n, nbr, weight = minvalue)
```

networkx has easy to use functions for plotting of graphs. You can reference [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/latest/tutorial.html#drawing-graphs).